# How to resolve 404 on gitlab nuget packages url?

Tags: c#, .net, gitlab, nuget

We are using: GitLab Enterprise Edition 11.1.4-ee

On GitLab docs, it says:

```bash
nuget source Add -Name "GitLab" -Source "https://myprivateurl/api/v4/projects/myprojectid/packages/nuget/index.json" -UserName user -Password pass
```

My role on the project is **maintainer**.

I got 404, no matter if I try to add source or to open that URL. What is strange as well is that I don't see $CI_API_V4_URL.

If I open: https://myprivateurl/api/v4/projects/myprojectid I can see project info.

Do I need some special permission for this?

I just spoke to admin, and he is getting 404 as well.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nuget package registry was introduced in GitLab 12.8 so it won't be present in version 11.1